# XMLHttpRequest with multiple queries

Tags: javascript

I have an interface that need user to input zip code, then I will query the longitude and latitude from a remote site based on the inputted zip, then query some population information based on previous queried longitude and latitude. I need 3 XMLhttpRequest() to query three different sites. Each query will based on previous queried data.  I think there may have some callback issues in my code, I don't know how to fix it.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Get City" onclick="getInfo()">

  <script> 
  function getInfo(getGeoCode) {
        var zipCode = document.getElementById("inputtext").value

        var xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlReq.open("GET", "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/" + zipCode, true);
        xmlReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlReq.readyState == 4) {
                var temp = JSON.parse(xmlReq.responseText);
                var lat = temp.places[[0]].latitude ;
                var logt = temp.places[[0]].longitude;
                getGeoCode(lat, logt);
            };
        };

        xmlReq.send();
    }

    function getGeoCode(lat,logt,getpop) {
        var nereq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        nereq.open("GET", "https://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?&latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + logt + "&showall=false&format=json", true);
        nereq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (nereq.readyState == 4) {
                var temp2 = JSON.parse(nereq.responseText);
                var stateCode = temp2.State.FIPS;
                var contyCode = temp2.County.FIPS;
                getpop(stateCode, contyCode);
            };
        };
        nereq.send();
    }

    function getpop(stateCode, contyCode) {
        var nereq2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        nereq2.open("GET", "http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?get=P0010001&for=county:" + contyCode + "&in=state:" + stateCode, true);
        nereq2.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (nereq2.readyState == 4) {
                var temp3 = JSON.parse(nereq.responseText);
                document.getElementById("fs").innerHTML = temp3;
            };
        };
        nereq2.send();
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: You are not passing third argument in `getGeoCode`.. Just use `function getGeoCode(lat,logt)` as `getpop` is under global context.. You can not invoke `undefined`

Comment: Take a look at Promises and [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions have arguments which conflict with the function names you call, so they are not accessible anymore.

For example, `getGeoCode` has an argument called `getpop`. When `getpop` is called, it does not call the function of that name, but tries to call the reference that the `getpop` argument references. Especially as you aren't passing anything in this paarmeter, it is most likely erroring.

The solution is to just remove the `getGeoCode` parameter from `getInfo()` and the `getpop` parameter from `getGeoCode()`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Get City" onclick="getInfo()">

  <script> 
  function getInfo() {
        var zipCode = document.getElementById("inputtext").value

        var xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlReq.open("GET", "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/" + zipCode, true);
        xmlReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlReq.readyState == 4) {
                var temp = JSON.parse(xmlReq.responseText);
                var lat = temp.places[[0]].latitude ;
                var logt = temp.places[[0]].longitude;
                getGeoCode(lat, logt);
            };
        };

        xmlReq.send();
    }

    function getGeoCode(lat,logt) {
        var nereq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        nereq.open("GET", "https://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?&latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + logt + "&showall=false&format=json", true);
        nereq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (nereq.readyState == 4) {
                var temp2 = JSON.parse(nereq.responseText);
                var stateCode = temp2.State.FIPS;
                var contyCode = temp2.County.FIPS;
                getpop(stateCode, contyCode);
            };
        };
        nereq.send();
    }

    function getpop(stateCode, contyCode) {
        var nereq2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        nereq2.open("GET", "http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?get=P0010001&for=county:" + contyCode + "&in=state:" + stateCode, true);
        nereq2.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (nereq2.readyState == 4) {
                var temp3 = JSON.parse(nereq.responseText);
                document.getElementById("fs").innerHTML = temp3;
            };
        };
        nereq2.send();
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: But the question is, when I debug into the var temp2 = JSON.parse(nereq.responseText); it gives me a run time error

Comment: then please edit the question to put in the details of the error and the response data. From your comment, it sounds like the response you are receiving from the server isn't valid JSON, but without details, that is just guessing

Comment: Yes, May be something wrong with the API, I will check that..Thanks